# How can I use the NLSClientScript extension in Yii?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

How can I use the extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nlsclientscript/ ?

I tried this:

config/main.php:

```
'clientScript' => array( 
'class' => 'ext.NLSClientScript',
```

views/layouts/main.php:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$systemJsPath = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(
     Yii::getPathOfAlias('system.web.js' ), false, -1, false );
$cs->registerScriptFile('jquery');
$cs->registerScriptFile( $systemJsPath . '/custom.js');
$cs->registerScriptFile( $systemJsPath . '/ext/plugins/jquery.form.js');
```

But it doesn't work. jQuery is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery is known as a core script in Yii and should be registered using [`CClientScript::registerCoreScript`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCoreScript-detail).

In your example:

```
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

The short names for all core scripts are listed in `YII_PATH/web/js/packages.php`.